# Export IPs from VMs running on Softlayer host

Tags: api, powershell, hyper-v, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to link up the IPs we have through Softlayer to their corresponding VM running in our various hosts.

IP inventory hasnt been the best.

I can use powershell to get the IPs and the VM names, but then it's data entry.

Can I gather this data and port it to the IP Management area in our SL account?

I want to take the VM name and put it in the "Notes" field in the IP Section in SL.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to link up the IPs from VMs running in a SoftLayer's host, probably you can submit a ticket and someone from internal department can provide any sight on this.

I can provide a request to edit the note for an ip address

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress/$ipId/editObject

Method: Post

{  
    "parameters":[  
        {  
            "note": "test 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have submitted a ticket and SL recommended to come to stackoverflow. They would not assist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer however!